# Implementing content from main method (Java) into Android Application?

Tags: java, android

I want to apply some code from a Java application I made earlier into my Android application that I am currently working on. This activity will contain an algorithm that I have written up to encrypt a message (using a simple substitution cipher). My main problem is this: I have two instance variables in the class and a main method, which obviously will not integrate well in Java, as follows.

```
public class subcipher_1 {

//Use Static variables so main class can recognize them
int key = 0;
static char ch;


/*Create main method
 *Will contain GUI prompts and encryption algorithms
 */
public static void main (String[] args){

    subcipher_1 converter = new subcipher_1();
    //Object created for the mesasage GUI
    converter.message();

}
```

For incorporating this into Android, ony of my ideas is to apply the content from the main method into the OnCreate, like below:

```
int key = 0;
static char ch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_next);


    JavaApplication2 converter = new JavaApplication2();
            converter.message();
}
```

However I am not sure how I will het this to work with the rest of the code? I was thinking of using an anonymous inner class howeevr my knowledge on this is very limited, and my instance variables are called in multiple methods.

Any advice will be appreciated greatly.